# Duplicated data when reloading view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data from a text file and pass the data to the database. The thing is, everytime I reload the view, the data gets sent and this means I get duplicated data, is there a way to keep this from happening? Perhaps truncating the file or saving the line number of the last line that was processed?

Also, the way the text files are generated is that I get a new text file everyday with the date on the name of the file so maybe another approach that I was thinking was to create a new database table where I would tag each file I process as "processed" so the function wont process more than one time the same file.

Here's an example of the text file:

```
1618 0002 9    9  505   04129284134    4141191269    4141191269 56984 4      002 001 4

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4         

1619 0000 9    6               1172    2129922686    2129922686       4      013     0

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4        

1619 0000 7    6  521         1188#          1172          1172       0          001 4

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4
```

---

And here is the function I'm using on my routes file:

```
Route::get('calls', function () {
    foreach (file(public_path() . "/calls.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
        $calls                 = new Calls();
        $calls->time           = trim(substr($line, 0, 4));
        $calls->duration       = trim(substr($line, 5, 4));
        $calls->cond_code      = trim(substr($line, 10, 1));
        $calls->code_dial      = trim(substr($line, 15, 1));
        $calls->code_used      = trim(substr($line, 18, 3));
        $calls->dialed_num     = trim(substr($line, 24, 11));
        $calls->calling_num    = trim(substr($line, 39, 11));
        $calls->clg_num_in_tac = trim(substr($line, 53, 11));
        $calls->auth_code      = trim(substr($line, 64, 5));
        $calls->frl            = trim(substr($line, 70, 1));
        $calls->ixc_code       = trim(substr($line, 77, 3));
        $calls->in_crt_id      = trim(substr($line, 85, 3));
        $calls->save();
    }
    return View::make('test')
        ->with('calls', Calls::all());

});
```

Comment: Is that a txt file or a tab-delimited csv?

Comment: Handling your form request through `get` route is a bad practice. Try looking at my solution below and see if it suits you.

Comment: @Jeff it's a text file with fixed width columns.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the implementation.

With the current implementation you would need to match each input with the database records if you'd need to restrict duplicates.

But it's a very bad design and highly discurraged.

What you instead do is add an `file input` field in your form and `POST` the form. Then handle the form like this.

```
Route::post('calls', function () {
    // your code goes here...
});
```

Once done you could redirect to another route.

Comment: The thing is I'm not using a form. I get the file from a directory, parse the information inside and then show the data on a table.